# Data encoding in python

Tags: python, image, encoding, binary

I download an image from newsgroups with the nntplib module in python. I then want to save the data to the file. I use:

```
news.group('alt.binaries.misc')  
data=''.join(news.body('<DhTgplpHcRsZMBTTw3i35@spot.net>')[-1])  
f=open('image.png','wb')  
f.write(data)  
f.close()
```

However, the saved file isn't a proper image file.
`data` is a string of the form:

```
'\x89PNG=B=C\x1a=C=A=A=A=BIHDR=A=A\x02X=A=A\x01Q\x08\x06=A=A=A\xa8\x81\xd3\x89=A=A=A\tpHYs=A=A\x0b\x13=A=A\x0b\x13\x01=A\x9a\x9c\x18=A=A etc... '
```

, with a lenght of 309530.
I can tell from the first bytes that the file should be a png file and the size also seems good to me, so I assume that the data is correct.
Does anyone knows what i'm doing wrong?

UPDATE:
I looked in the header of the article and its says: `Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1 Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit` I don't think this is very helpful with decoding the text, but who knows..

I also compared my string with regular headers of png files. This is `\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n`, or `\x89PNG\x0d\x0a\x1a\x0a`. (as alexis also stated)
I concluded that =B stands for \x0d, =C for \x0a and =A for \x00. <strike>I assume that the other \x..'s are not encoded, but i'm not sure (I don't know very much about encodings)</strike> update3 shows that they do differ.
What is an encoding that encodes this way?

UPDATE2:
the data: *-see below-* (`repr(data)`)

UPDATE3:
I was able to save the image with another program and then to open it in python. This is what the data should be. *-see below-*. 
The beginnings look kind of similar, but after that there is a big difference. What the hell is this encoding? it really frustrates me. (BTW, thanks for all the great help so far)

---

All the files: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1499291/python-encoding-question/index.html

Comment: The file writing is fine. There's something wrong with the data; are you sure it's being transferred as raw bytes, without any encoding issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NULL is replaced with "=A", CR with "=B", LF with "=C", and "=" with "=D", very similar to gZip 8bit ([http://www.imc.org/ietf-usefor/2003/Feb/0575.html][1]).

Answer (score 1):

looks like the data is uuencoded, so you have to decode it, before you write it to your image file.

you can verify this, when you `uudecode image.png` the file you have written with your above script.

Python has support for this in its [uu](http://docs.python.org/library/uu.html) module.

Comment: I had already tried uudecode and yenc. They both don't work. Also, the data doesn't have the begin and end tags of these encodings.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe `NNTP.body` is supposed to automatically decode article content, or is it? Have you looked at the article source? It should specify the encoding.

Anyway the PNG signature should start with \x89PNG, but should then be followed by 0d 0a (CR LF). This ain't it. Could it be base64 encoded, or some such? All those = signs look very familiar.

Comment: Thanks, but I tried base64 and it isn't it.   I updated the question, maybe you can figure it out with the extra info I gave there. Would it help if I upload the complete data somewhere?

Comment: It would certainly help if you could put up the raw article text-- but confirm that you can view the picture with a news client. The header says "8bit", so it might conceivably have gotten corrupted somewhere. Better yet, if you could point us to an article on a news server everyone can access--gmane doesn't seem to have alt.binaries.misc, for example.

Comment: I updated the question, hope it helps. It is a binary server, so I thinks that's why gmane hasn't it. You could use free.xsusenet.com, it requires a login but is totally free. check xsusenet.com.

Comment: btw, i can save other articles on the server which use yenc perfectly fine, so the server is not the problem. The main question is now, I think, 'What encoding is this?'

Comment: Where is the rest of the article text? Anyway it SAYS it's 8bit. You should have mentioned that from the beginning. If you can read other articles, I'm now guessing that it simply got corrupted in transit. Can your newsreader display it?

Comment: Yes, another program is able to show the picture, so the picture isn't corrupted. The reason I think the 8-bit isn't important, is,  that other articles, which are yenc encoded, or any other encoding, also say 8-bit in the header. The data I uploaded is all of the article's text, do you also need the complete header off the article? besides the encoding things I posted, it doesn't contain useful information.

Comment: There's no way to reproduce your code snippet unless you provide a link to an accessible newsgroup article-- and no way to ensure that you haven't missed something essential.

Comment: well, as far as I know, there are no binary usenetservers which you can access without authentication. Maybe you are confusing text and binary servers? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usenet_newsgroup#Binary_newsgroups    However, I'm pretty sure that the problem is not the server. I tried  to download similar files, wich all have this strange encoding. Other files, which are yenc-encoded, can be decoded fine, so it's not the server's fault. Other programs are also able to download the files which have this encoding.

Comment: I was able to get the original image, see UPDATE3

Comment: I'm not saying it's the server's fault, I'm saying it's hard to debug your problem blind. Sorry but personally, I've no interest in reverse-engineering your string pair. If I could see the entire file I might learn something by helping you out.

Comment: With 'the entire file', do you mean the file I get? You can find all the files here now: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1499291/python-encoding-question/index.html, or is there anything else you need? Of course I didn't expect you to reverse-engineer the encoding, I only hoped that you would recognize the encoding. And thanks for the all the help!

Comment: I meant the entire posting, with full NNTP headers, not just the attachment.

Comment: Ok, I uploaded the full article, incl. headers. See previous link. I saved it with `f.write(repr(news.article(article)[-1]))`, is that the way you want it?

Comment: I was asking for the original posting, not for what python spits out after it chews on it. I don't know any other ways to ask for that.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I really don't know how to give you that. Can you explain to me how I can save the post for you?